# react-native-swiper scrollBy()

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I'll preface this by saying I'm very new to react native. I'm creating an app that uses react-native-swiper to swipe through three screens. Swipe functionality works, however, I would like to include two buttons on each page that allow the user to jump to the other two screens (from the documentation this is possible with scrollBy()).

I read that a reference to the swiper must be created in order to access the method, but I'm not sure how to access that from within each screen component, or how to pass that reference down. Again, I'm very new to react native and am trying to understand how it works.

Within each component I have imported the buttons that will be used to navigate to the other screens. In the parent class I have created a reference.

Parent Class:

```
export default class MainView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper 
        showsPagination={false} 
        loop={false}
        index={1}
        ref={(swiper) => {this._swiper = swiper;}}
        >

        <Jar />

        <Home />

        <Awesome />

      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}
```

One of the buttons used inside the components:

```
export default class JarButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => {}}>
              <Image style={styles.img} source={jarPic} resizeMode="center"/> 
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm assuming all I need to do is pass the reference down to the component, then to the button in order to allow the onPress() to navigate to the correct screen using the scrollBy() method.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the value you want to reference, so you only need to execute the corresponding scroll function.

**Methods**

```
scrollBy(index, animated)
```

**Scroll by relative index.**

[Link to module](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#scrollbyindex-animated)

```
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.swiper.scrollBy(1)}>
          <Image style={styles.img} source={jarPic} resizeMode="center"/> 
        </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: When I try that I get an 'undefined is not and object' error. Not sure why, or if I can access this.swiper.scrollBy() from within the component.

Comment: @flabbergasted Do not use the button you made yourself. Failed to refer to value.

Comment: So I should use react native button? What does "Failed to refer to value" mean? I'm very unfamiliar with react native and am trying to understand.

Comment: I mean, the button you want to use should be on the Swiper screen.